# no alert when two value are called with jquery

Tags: jquery, alert

Neither of the alert box works for following code -

```
var genvalue=('input[#gender]:checked').val());
alert (genvalue);

var value = $("#edu_det1").val();
alert (value);
```

But when  genvalue, the whole portion of code is remove it work. Don't know what the problem

Comment: Is the missing $ in your first line a typo or the reason for the problem :) ?

Comment: There is also one closing bracket too many on that line. The reason that you're not seeing any of the alerts is that the code stops executing after the first faulty line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get an element with an ID, just target that ID as it should be unique :

```
var genvalue = $('#gender').val();
alert (genvalue);

var value = $("#edu_det1").val();
alert (value);
```

Otherwise you can also do :

```
var genvalue = $('input[id="gender"]:checked').val();
```

But that sort of defeats the point of having an ID !

Comment: using in such way by id generating undefined for genvalue `<input name="gender" type="radio"  value="Male" onchange="locs()">&nbsp;Male&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input name="gender" type="radio"  value="Female" onchange="locs()">&nbsp;Female` when using id, only male value comes

Comment: Well, do you see an ID in that markup. How about targeting the name instead, like so : `$('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();`

Answer (score 3):

you are missing $. (jquery object). try to include your jquery library. or else you can use Jquery CDN

```
var genvalue=('input[#gender]:checked').val());// here $ is missing
```

use the CDN

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
```

Comment: I don't really get how you deduce a missing jQuery library from the question …

Comment: @adeneo [#gender] is Logical mistake of user. code is breaking in the first line only. due to missing jquery library.

Comment: @Ravi - and how exactly did you figure out jQuery is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct code and you have missed $

```
var genvalue=$('input[#gender]:checked').val());
alert (genvalue);

var value = $("#edu_det1").val();
alert (value);
```

If you are applying something else then it might not work properly. The correction as per your code is that much only but if you need more correction still getting wrong you need to give some more code snippets.

Well try this to get more information and learn about [jquery value selection method](http://api.jquery.com/val/)